# Meshgriding an array with itself n times, in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Assume tht `x` is a 1 dimensional array in Python. How can we compute its n-times meshgrid with itself, without writing it n-times? For example, for n=8, I want a command to do

`a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8 = numpy.meshgrid(x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x)`

but without writing `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8` and `x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
mesh = np.meshgrid(*[x]*8)
```

and you can access `mesh[0], mesh[1]`, etc.